# VirtualHost keeps redirecting to default main page

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, virtualhost

I was wondering if im doing something wrong or what ? I'm trying to create a virtualhost for my web page. I've got default apache conf in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
         Options FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www>
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride None
         Order allow, deny
         allow from all
   </Directory>

   ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ usr/lib/cgi-bin/
   <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
         AllowOverride None
         Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
         Order allow, deny
         Allow from all
   </Directory>
```

and my own virtualhost conf file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/mywebpage
   ServerName aaa.bbb.cc
   ServerAlias www.aaa.bbb.cc
</VirtualHost>
```

And all i got is default page of Apache on http://aaa.bbb.cc

Answer (score 0):

you must create a link to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled and reload the server.

```
ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/myownvirtualhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/myownvirtualhost.conf   
service apache2 restart
```